# How to find the most frequent value based on dates in another column in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to find which value occurs on a given day 50% of the time or more. For example, in the dataset below, A occurs the most frequently on 06/21, however it does not occur 50% of the time or more. On 06/22, B occurs 50% of the time or more, so I would need the output to show me "B" and the date "06/22"

```
import pandas as pd

# initialise data of lists.
data = {'Name':['A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B','B','B', 'C', 'C'], 'Date': 
['06/21', '06/21', '06/21', '06/21', '06/21', '06/21', '06/21', '06/22' , '06/22', '06/22', '06/22', '06/22', '06/22']}

# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Print the output.
print(df)
```

| Name | Date |
| --- | --- |
| A | 06/21 |
| B | 06/21 |
| A | 06/21 |
| C | 06/21 |
| C | 06/21 |
| A | 06/21 |
| B | 06/21 |
| A | 06/22 |
| B | 06/22 |
| B | 06/22 |
| B | 06/22 |
| C | 06/22 |
| C | 06/22 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summary of the problem:

- Inputs: Given a date
- Output: The freq of which values in column Name is greater than 50 percent

```py
import numpy as np # If not downloaded run 'pip install numpy'
date=input('Enter your date ex:06/21')
#date='06/21'
def frequency(df,date):
    dfcrop=df[df['Date']==date]#Crop the columns with given date
    dfcrop=df[df['Accepted']==True]# As per condition
    values=list()
    for value in set(list(dfcrop['Name'])): # Take out all unique names
        freq=np.sum((dfcrop['Name']==value).astype(np.int32))
        freq=freq/dfcrop.shape[0]# Calculate frequency
        if freq >=0.5: # frequency is greater than 50 percent
           values.append(value)
    return values
freq=frequency(df,date) # freq is a list with the names with a freq above 50 percent on given date
```

```
dates_to_use=[<put all dates to use>]

df=df[df.date.isin(dates_to_use)==False]
```

If you want to use only some selected dates do this as per what the author asked in comments

Comment: I updated my answer

Answer (score 4):

You can use `value_counts` with normalize to count the relative values, then filter:

```
s = df.groupby('Date')['Name'].value_counts(normalize=True).reset_index(name='freq')
s.query('freq >= 0.5')
```

Output:

```
    Date Name  freq
3  06/22    B   0.5
```